# Tf command line password authentication TF30063

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, version-control, command-line-interface

I am creating an app that uses the tf command line to interact with TFS, however I am unable to connect to my server via the command line. If i am signed into Visual Studio, it works fine, also if I actually use the command line, and type my credentials into the login prompt that pops up, I am able to connect. I also am able to connect via the website: xxxx.visualstudios.com/defualtcollection. The only issue is that I am unable to connect when just typing in a command in the command line, when signed out of VS. When I log in to VS i use jacob@xxxx.com ...the documentation for the command line says : `-login:domain\username,password` or `-login:username@domain,password` as a flag in the command. Right now I am using this command:

```
tf info "C:\Users\Jacob\Documents\TestTfs\AnotherNewProject\test.cs" /login:jacob@xxxx.com,MyPassword  /recursive
```

and it does not work. I have tried without the .com, and moving the xxx.com and many other variations. Does anyone else see what my error is? Again if I do not provide the `/login:`info, I am prompted in a separate window to enter my credentials and it works fine, so I do not think it is the file path or the "tf info" that is throwing off my command. Also it has my workspace name in the error message : `TF30063: You are not authorized to access xxxx.visualstudio.com\DefaultCollection.`

I AM using vs13, and I know that that is the correct path for the version of TF.exe that I am using (aka I am not using the VS15 tf.exe to connect)

Comment: anybody halp  =(?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the cmd at my side, it works correctly.

Try below ways to fix it:

1. Log out of Visual Studio Online from all browsers and VS.
2. Remove the existing credential from **credential manager**(Control panel > Credential manager, which contained the previous password)
3. Clear cache from C:\Users\ [your username]
   \AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache
   password.)
4. Just run the Developer Command Prompt for VS2013 under Visual Studio
   Tools in your VS2013 folder.
5. Run "**devenv /resetuserdata**" to clear your logon for Visual Studio 2013. Let it finish, it may take a while.
6. Launch Visual Studio, connect to the Visual Studio Online project again with your account.
7. Just run below cmd, not specify the credential to check if that works. (Based on my test, you don't need to specify the credential again in command line once the VS connected the the online project.)

   `tf info "C:\Users\Jacob\Documents\TestTfs\AnotherNewProject\test.cs" /recursive`
8. Try your command with the credential specified to check if that
   works. (**Make sure your have enter the correct user name and
   password**)

[image]

Comment: the issue is that I wanted to be able to do it while not logged into VS, and to be able to login through the command line (without the VSO prompt that pops up). But it does appear after some research that this is the only way to do it as MSFT did not put any effort into working with the LiveId's in this case. I will accept the answer though.